# Как передать в javascript файл с input?

Tags: javascript, xml

Делаю программу, которая будет брать параметры с XML и работать с ними. Записывать ничего не надо, только читать. XML файл находится на локальном диске, не на сервере.

Как его передать в javascript? Можно запросить файл с помощью тега `input`, но как его передать в сам скрипт? Или, если такое невозможно, подскажите, как проще всего решить вопрос с чтением XML с диска пользователя напрямую?

Comment: Чтение "Диска пользователя" это запрещённый приём. Зачем это вам? Пользуйтесь cookie или local storage. Вы можете воспользоваться new ActiveXObject("msxml.domdocument"), ф-ция load, но у вас будут пробемы с безопасностью. Прийдётся нажимать кнопки разрешить, или может быть запрещён доступ к файлу.

Comment: Копать в сторону `input[type='file']` и `File API` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Объект для чтения файлов/буферов данных
let fr = new FileReader();

// Слушаем изменения
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  // Проверочки всякие
  if(this.files.length === 0)
    return;
  
  let file = this.files[0];
  if(file.type !== 'text/xml') // Если тип не XML - выходим
    return;
  
  // Прочиталось!
  fr.onload = e => {
    // Используем великое колдунство для парсинга из строки в DOM
    let dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(fr.result, "application/xml");
    console.info('Самый всамделишный DOM из XML:', dom);
  };
  
  // Читаем как строку объект File (да, тот, что генерирует input[type='file'])
  fr.readAsText(file);
});
```

```html
<input type='file' id='file' accept='application/xml' />
```